# JSON data update not showing up on webpage

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I want the value on my webpage to change, as the value in the JSON file changes. I wrote an interval function- `intervalFunction()` but the page does not update. Here is my code :

```
<html>
   <head>
      <meta content = "text/html; charset = ISO-8859-1" http-equiv = "content-type">

      <script type = "application/javascript">
         var myVar;


         function intervalFunction() {
            myVar = setInterval(loadJSON(), 100);
         }

         function loadJSON(){
            var data_file = "http://52.21.92.17/balance";
            var http_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            try{
               http_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            }catch (e){
               // IE
            try{
               http_request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");

            }catch (e) {

               try{
                  http_request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
               }catch (e){
                  alert("Your browser broke!");
                  return false;
               }

               }
            }

            http_request.onreadystatechange = function(){

               if (http_request.readyState == 4  ){
                  // Javascript function JSON.parse to parse JSON data
                  var jsonObj = JSON.parse(http_request.responseText);

                  // jsonObj variable now contains the data structure and can
                  // be accessed as jsonObj.name and jsonObj.country.
                  document.getElementById("Address").innerHTML = jsonObj[0].address;
                  document.getElementById("Balance").innerHTML = jsonObj[0].etherBalance;
               }
            }

            http_request.open("GET", data_file, true);
            http_request.send();
         }

      </script>

   </head>

   <body onload="intervalFunction()">
      <table class = "src">
         <tr><th>Address</th><th>Balance</th></tr>
         <tr><td><div id = "Address"></div></td>
         <td><div id = "Balance"></div></td></tr>
      </table>
   </body>

</html>
```

Furthermore, another question I have is when use index [1], I can see data on the webpage, but if I use  index [0], the first set of data in the array does not appear. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Answered the first part below. The second part is hard to answer without either seeing your data (if that's what your indexing by 1), and/or whatever part of the code is indexing something by 1.

Comment: Hi ! I removed the parenthesis but the page still  doesn't update. The JSON data is here : [link](http://52.21.92.17/balance). As the value changes, I am hoping it updates the webpage without the need to refresh it .

Comment: Any errors in your [JavaScript console](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers)? Is 52.21.92.17 the same machine running the web page? If not, you may have a [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) issue.

Comment: I get the following error on my google chrome JS console. https://gyazo.com/44a4ea28b3088da9883acfa572ac79aa

Comment: Yep. You're trying to make an AJAX request to another domain, and the appropriate headers aren't in place to allow that. Visit the link in my last comment for more info.

Comment: Apologies but I am fairly new to Javascript and AJAX. I briefly read the documentation but I still don't decipher why I am getting this error. Am I missing something in  my code ?

Comment: By default (from the site I linked above), "a web application using XMLHttpRequest could only make HTTP requests to the domain it was loaded from, and not to other domains. "  See that link, or Google CORS, for more info. I am *not* the guy with the answers on fixing this problem, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

```
 function intervalFunction() {
   myVar = setInterval(loadJSON(), 100);
 }
```

is like saying:

```
 function intervalFunction() {
    var something = loadJSON();
    myVar = setInterval(something, 100);
 }
```

You're calling `loadJSON()` once, immediately, then asking `setInterval()` to call its result as a function.

You mean to say:

```
 function intervalFunction() {
   myVar = setInterval(loadJSON, 100);
 }
```

Comment: Hi ! I removed the parenthesis but the page still doesn't update.